# Tkinter Display Label does not udpate

Tags: python, tkinter

The displayed score on the Tkinter window does not update on each loop. But if you check in the terminal score is been updated

Tk Window does not update
[image]

The terminal score has been updated
[image]

```
score = 0

def check():
    global score
    if answered_question[1]['correct_answer'] == 'True':
        score += 1

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(padx=20, pady=20, bg=BLUE_GRAY)

score_board = tk.Label(
    text=f"Score: {score}",
    bg=BLUE_GRAY, fg="white",
    font=('Arial', 10, "normal")
)

check_btn = tk.Button(image=check_img, command=check, highlightthickness=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *WHY* would the Label update?  You set its text once, when you initially created it, and have done absolutely nothing to change it afterwards.

Comment: Just updating `score` will not update the text of the label, you need to update the text of the label explicitly.

Comment: @jasonharper sorry, didn't understand it right away. :) I'm still learning and doing it on my own. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the label explicitly by using either `config`/`configure` (same thing), or by binding a `tk.StringVar()` to your `Label`'s `textvariable` parameter

```
# Option One
def check():
    global score
    if answered_question[1]['correct_answer'] == 'True':
        score += 1
        # update the label
        score_board.configure(text=f'Score: {score}')
```

*or...*

```
# Option Two
def check():
    global score
    if answered_question[1]['correct_answer'] == 'True':
        score += 1
        # update the label
        label_var.set(f'Score: {score}')

...  # code omitted for brevity

label_var = tk.StringVar()  # declare a tk.StringVar to bind to your label

score_board = tk.Label(
    text=f"Score: {score}",
    bg=BLUE_GRAY, fg="white",
    font=('Arial', 10, "normal"),
    textvariable=label_var,  # the label will update whenever this var is 'set'
)
```